# Proving limit of a 2D sequence using $\epsilon-N$ definition

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I'm practicing proving a limit of a sequence $a_n:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and I would like to know if I'm doing things correctly. The original limit is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\langle\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{n^2+4n+5}{n^2+1}\right\rangle=\langle0,1\rangle$$
I have already dealt with the first component, which suggests that $N=\lceil 1-\log_2\epsilon\rceil$ is sufficient, since we have
$$\left|\frac{1}{2^n}-0\right|=2^{-n}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}~~\implies~~1-n<\log_2\epsilon~~\implies~~N=\left\lceil1-\log_2\epsilon\right\rceil$$

I'm having just a bit of trouble with the second component. Here's my preliminary analysis for it.
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{n^2+4n+5}{n^2+1}-1\right|&=4\left|\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right|\\
&\le4\left|\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right|\\
&\le4\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}$$
Since I can't solve the inequality for $n$ directly, would I have to split this up to establish something like $\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{n}<\dfrac{\epsilon}{16}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{16}=\dfrac{\epsilon}{8}$?

If this is right, then it would seem to me that choosing $N=\max\left\{\left\lceil1-\log_2\epsilon\right\rceil,\left\lceil\dfrac{16}{\epsilon}\right\rceil,\left\lceil\dfrac{4}{\sqrt\epsilon}\right\rceil\right\}$ will suffice for the proof. Can anyone confirm? Help is appreciated!

**Edit:** I forgot to include one quick question I had. Before using $\dfrac{n+1}{n^2+1}\le\dfrac{n+1}{n^2}$ I elected to try $\dfrac{1}{n}\le\dfrac{n+1}{n^2+1}$. Does this also work for a proof like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question but I think you are making things more complicated than it needs to be for the proof.  $1/n^2 < 1/n$ for any $n > 1$ so the second to last inequality is $< 4(1/n + 1/n)$.  i.e. $8/n$.  Then given an $\epsilon$ chose $n > 8 / \epsilon$.

Comment: It definitely helps making the proof more streamlined. Thanks for the suggestion. It actually does answer the first question I posed, but I'm still wondering if my second comparison is also valid.

Comment: Fair enough.  The latter two values in the maxima seem sufficient to make the statement.  Why do you require $1 - \log_2\epsilon$ ?

Comment: I see, for the other component.  Then yes, I agree that is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the one in the edit. The difference here is that I would compare to a sequence that is smaller $(\frac{1}{n})$ as opposed to a larger one. $(\frac{n+1}{n^2})$ I've consulted a professor who agreed with the latter, but I didn't get a chance to bring up this second sequence.